# Fit data with multiple functions

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I am trying to fit my data with multiple fitting functions consisting of multiple variables. An example is below for two variables. There are cases where for a certain variable the fit is not good and I get a singular gradient error. I would like to ignore those cases and proceed anyway and furthermore for the remaining variables take the better solution between the two fitting function by comparing the deviance. Like in this example for both type1 and type2 the sum of residuals is less with the first function
`sum(resid(myfitfun1)^2)` < `sum(resid(myfitfun2)^2)`  so take the first function for both of the  variables.

```
myfun1<-function(x,a,b){1/(1+exp(-(x/a)+b))}
myfun2<-function(x,a,b){1+b*exp(-(x)/a)} 
   
mydata <- data.frame(v=c("type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1",
"type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1",
 "type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1",
 "type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type2","type2","type2","type2",
                     "type2","type2"), 
 m=c(1.116975672,1.38641493,1.423833959,1.482008121,1.513588607,1.527179033,
                     1.543512539,1.555874185,1.607579807,1.721182154,1.729059048,1.748226681,
                     1.774814055,1.815147988,1.835638421,1.854582642,1.861972,1.887704144,
                     1.915360975,1.948689331,1.97516491,1.985962227,2.011310496,2.043716548,
                     2.068918438,2.091184665,2.120366813,2.126865141,2.148241318,2.15871161,
                     2.193529738,2.256197915,2.302364722,2.316381935,2.31909683,2.325213451,
                     2.336299128,2.410419652,2.473160411,2.478302702,2.5238233,2.651124474,
                     2.70470831,2.927536062,-0.1736072,0.1235610,0.5848941,0.9016486,0.9744832,
                     1.2767238), 
 n=c(0.022727273,0.045454545,0.068181818,0.090909091,0.113636364,0.136363636,
                     0.159090909,0.181818182,0.204545455,0.227272727,0.25,0.272727273,0.295454545,
                     0.318181818,0.340909091,0.363636364,0.386363636,0.409090909,0.431818182,
                     0.454545455,0.477272727,0.5,0.522727273,0.545454545,0.568181818,0.590909091,
                     0.613636364,0.636363636,0.659090909,0.681818182,0.704545455,0.727272727,0.75,
                     0.772727273,0.795454545,0.818181818,0.840909091,0.863636364,0.886363636,
                     0.909090909,0.931818182,0.954545455,0.977272727,1,0.1666667,0.3333333,0.5000000,
                     0.6666667,0.8333333,1))
myfitfun1 <- nls(n~myfun1(m,a,b),mydata,start=list(a=1,b=1))
myfitfun2 <- nls(n~myfun2(m,a,b),mydata,start=list(a=1,b=1))
```

I would like to program it in a way that it handels automatically the better fit between the two functions for various `type` and ignoring in case of an error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put both functions in a function and work with `tryCatch`. In the one `tryCatch`es, just throw an `NA` to overcome the error. In another `tryCatch` set the value to `Inf` when an error occurs to ensure the "better" fit for the non-failing function. In normal cases the minimum is chosen. With `` `attr<-` `` we can give the MSE as an attribute to the output of the fit.

```
fun <- function(data) {
  myfitfun1 <- tryCatch(
    nls(n ~ myfun1(m, a, b), data, start=list(a=1, b=1)),
    error=function(e) NA)
  myfitfun2 <- tryCatch(
    nls(n ~ myfun2(m, a, b), data, start=list(a=1, b=1)),
    error=function(e) NA)
  L <- list(myfitfun1, myfitfun2)
  res <- sapply(L, function(x) {
    tryCatch(sum(resid(x)^2), error=function(e) Inf)
    })
  `attr<-`(L[[which.min(res)]], "MSE", min(res))
}

fun(mydata)
# Nonlinear regression model
# model: n ~ myfun1(m, a, b)
# data: data
# a      b 
# 0.3465 5.6461 
# residual sum-of-squares: 2.323
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 26 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.675e-06
```

To get the `MSE` attribute, use:

```
attr(fun(mydata), "MSE")
# [1] 2.322945
```

Comment: I strongly recommend making `a,b,m,n` arguments to your `fun` . Otherwise unexpected 'grabs' of the wrong datasets may occur.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sure, that's a point, the `data` argument should suffice, right? However, the purpose of the question and thus of my answer was to give the OP the idea of how to deal with these error cases, and it was actually not intended to be a fully working takeover solution.

Comment: Fair enough :-)